# Variable Datasource is undefined

Tags: coldfusion, oracle11g, coldfusion-9

I have defined a datasource in the admin console of ColdFusion Admin. I have declared the configuration with the same datasource name in set_datasource_util file. I have a webpage that connects to a DB(Oracle) using the datasource given and it works fine most of the time. But lately I am starting to see exceptions like "Variable datasource-name(my app name) is undefined". I am not able to identify the root cause as I am not able to recreate it as it works most of the time. I can say on average on 1000 hits of page, it fails 1 time with that exception. Can anyone help in identifying what could be the possible issue so that I can investigate in that direction.

I have configured WOCD080P_ABC in CFAdmin.

Below is the code from Application.cfm

```
<cfif client.securityLevel NEQ ''>
    <cfinvoke component="#siteroot#.CFC.Set_Data_Source_Util" method="fnSetABCDataSource" returnvariable="ABCDataSourceDefinition">
        <cfinvokeargument name="Environment" value="#variables.thisServerType#" />
    </cfinvoke>
    <cfif ABCDataSourceDefinition.DataSource NEQ 'Error'>
        <cfset DATASOURCE_ABC = ABCDataSourceDefinition.DataSource />
        <cfset DBUSER_ABC = ABCDataSourceDefinition.DBUser />
        <cfset DBPASSWORD_ABC = ABCDataSourceDefinition.DBPassword />
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Below is the code from Set_datasource_UTil :

```
<cffunction name="fnSetABCDataSource" access="public" returntype="struct">
    <cfargument name="Environment" type="string" required="yes">

    <cfset ReturnParameters = StructNew() />

    <cfif Environment IS 'prod'>
        <cfset ReturnParameters.DataSource = 'WOCD080P_ABC' />
        <cfset ReturnParameters.DBUser = ''/>
        <cfset ReturnParameters.DBPassword = '' />
    <cfelse>
        <cfset ReturnParameters.DataSource = 'WOCD080T_ABC'/>
        <cfset ReturnParameters.DBUser = ''/>
        <cfset ReturnParameters.DBPassword = '' />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn ReturnParameters>
</cffunction>
```

Below is the code which i am executing from HTML file.

```
<cfinvoke component="#siteroot#.cfc.ABC_UTIL" method="GetRegion" returnVariable = "USregion" >
    <cfinvokeargument name="dbSource" value=#DATASOURCE_ABC# />
    <cfinvokeargument name="dbUser" value=#DBUSER_ABC# />
    <cfinvokeargument name="dbPass" value=#DBPASSWORD_ABC# />
</cfinvoke>
```

The code in the HTML file works most of the time but breaks sometime with error Variable DATASOURCE_ABC not defined.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: The last time I was running into this error because the server was going OOM due to a rogue process eating all the available resources randomly. I'd check your server logs and any monitoring software you may be using.

Comment: Are you setting the datasource as a property of the Application.cfc, as in `this.datasource = 'datasource_name'`? If so, please post the relevant code from your Application.cfc and a snippet from your set_datasource_util file where you are declaring the configuration.

Comment: I have Modified the question and added code snippets. Please check and advice. Thanks for reply

Comment: From your code it looks like you are only setting `DATASOURCE_ABC` when `<cfif ABCDataSourceDefinition.DataSource NEQ 'Error'>`. Could it be set to 'Error' on occasion and therefore your `DATASOURCE_ABC` variable is not being set?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you are using the var keyword for local variables inside of CFC Functions:

```
<cfset var ReturnParameters = StructNew() />
```

CF9+ local scope can be used in lieu of var:

```
<cfset local.ReturnParameters = StructNew() />
```

For extra protection, improve this statement in your application.cfm:

```
<cfif isDefined("ABCDataSourceDefinition.DataSource") 
    AND ABCDataSourceDefinition.DataSource NEQ 'Error'>
    <cfset DATASOURCE_ABC = ABCDataSourceDefinition.DataSource />
    <cfset DBUSER_ABC = ABCDataSourceDefinition.DBUser />
    <cfset DBPASSWORD_ABC = ABCDataSourceDefinition.DBPassword />
</cfif>
```

Also, the  could be another source of why a datasource is not being defined. I assume you have an interceptor that catches that before this datasource error occurs and sends them to a login page or something.